# PHP print_r in html

Tags: php

I have a html

```
<html>
<body>

{$array['name']}<br />
{$array['nick']}
</body>
</html>
```

how can I `print_r` an `$array`? I can't remember how does this think names. So I can't google it.

Comment: `print_r` has a second parameter which returns the output instead of echo'ing it, so you can simply use: `echo '<pre>' . print_r($array, true) . '</pre>'`. To make sure you replace HTML characters, use `htmlentities`: `echo '<pre>' . htmlentities(print_r($array, true), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '</pre>'`

Comment: If this is a smarty template: you can do `{$array|@print_r}`. Alternatively you can add `{debug}` to the end of your template to view all available variables.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? It doesn't work in your templating language? It doesn't return the array? What you're asking is "*I have a car and I can't turn it on*" and someone tells you to put in the key and your answer is "*it doesn't work*". We have no idea what your setup looks like or what doesn't work. The only answer we can currently give is "fix it" as we don't even know if you're using a templating system. Is your *actual* question "how to use `print_r` in smarty"?

Comment: Seriously? You can not use Google? http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: It seems you are using some PHP framework

Comment: @h2ooooooo this is a correct answer. You should add it.

Comment: @dewd It is indeed correct as per OP's question title, however it is not correct as per what OP actually seemed to want (mind you this answer is over 7 years old).

Answer (score 4):

You can print array in php as below

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php print_r($array); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using some PHP framework.

If you are using Laravel, you can output your array values by using the double curly braces `{{ $array['key'] }}`.

So, you code will like:

```
<html>
<body>

{{$array['name']}}<br />
{{$array['nick']}}

</body>
</html>
```

But if you want to `print_r` the array, you can use `dd($array)` to print the array.